# Number of referee nodes required in distributed leader election algorithm

Tags: graphs, distributed-systems

I know the reason as to why $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$ referee nodes are required. What I don't understand is how to arrive at that value, when I have $7\log n$ candidate nodes. Please forgive me if this is common knowledge, I am new to the field.